# Загрузка больших файлов через REST API

Tags: java, golang

Я пишу файловое хранилище и хочу улучшить его работу. Загружаются файлы большого размера, кроме этого, после загрузки надо запретить их изменение, поэтому они хранятся в MongoDB GridFS.

Загружаются файлы через REST API в три этапа:

1. start-запрос начинает транзакцию (на самом деле транзакций еще нет), создает временный файл с временным ID, сохраняет мета-информацию о файле и возвращает временный ID
2. append-запрос дописывает байты в конец файла. Вместе с байтами отправляется временный ID файла, к которому дописываем байты
3. commit - перегоняет файл с диска в GridFS

Как это лучше реализовать? Я решил для всего использовать временный ID. При старт-запросе генерируется уникальный tempID и создается файл на диске, имя файла такое же как tempID. При append-запросе отправляется tempID. Обработчик получает tempID, открывает файл с таким именем на диске и дописывает к нему байты. Commit-запрос получает tempID в заголовке и перегоняет файл с таким именем с диска в монгу.

Можно ли реализовать это красивее и надежнее?

Как прикрутить к этому транзакции, чтобы если не произошел коммит, то мета-информация о файла не сохраняется в базе?

Языки: джава или гоу.

Comment: Насколько я знаю в mongoDB нет транзакции. А что вам мешает сразу данные писать в БД?

Comment: @Евгений Гаврилов, данные приходят в хранилище порциями, а монго не поддерживает дописывание в грид фс